# Why doesn't the rect parameter work in pygame fill?

Tags: python, pygame

In the module pygame the `Surface.fill` has a parameter called `rect=[]`.

in my code, I'm loading in an 8by8 pixel of water with an adjustable level. 1 to 8 pixels tall.

```
for x in range(len(screen)):
    for y in range(len(screen[x])):
        if screen[x][y] == 0:
            box.fill((0,0,0))
        elif screen[x][y] == 9:
            box.fill((255,255,255))
        else:
            box.fill((0,0,255), rect = [x*8,y*8+8-screen[x][y],8,screen[x][y]])
        window.blit(box, (x*8,y*8))
```

`box` is `pygame.Surface((8,8))`

The `screen` list is the entire screen

I'm using the `screen` list to map out the entire screen using values from `0to9`, where `9` is a solid platform, `8to1` is water level, and `0` is nothing

This code loads in each `screen` value as a type of 8by8 pixel(`0to9`). (since I'm using 8by8 pixels the list is 100 long and my screen is 800 pixels long hence the *8).

In the `box.fill` part I'm filling in `box` with blue and I'm using the `rect` parameter to draw a `rect` the size of (`8` long and water level or `screen` value tall), and I'm placing that at `x*8`(formula explained earlier) and `y*8` and adding `8-screen[x][y]` which is moving the rect down so that the water item is the proper height.

My issue is, is that the water pixels aren't loading in.

Comment: First of all, you dont want `x*8,y*8` in the rect argument as the box is 8x8 and if its the 3 box along, x would be 24, which is not on the box, so `x,y`. As far as the `+8-screen[x][y]`, not sure what you are trying to achieve, do you want the higher the water level, the higher up on the box it draws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rect argument is to fill in an area on the surface, the surface your trying to fill in 8x8 big, at the first pixel chunk, it works correctly because 0*8 is 0, but when you get to the second pixel chunk, its trying to fill at 8-16 on the x axis, which is not on the 8x8 box, you want to to start at the 0 (on the x axis).

```
box.fill((0,0,255), rect=(0,8-screen[x][y],8,screen[x][y]))
```

Comment: So the x and y placement is on the surface and not the screen

Comment: @gamersbeware yes, its the x and y position of that surface (which could be the screen) you are filling, which in this case is is the box.